# One day, I was thinking about Jesus and I mistakenly said that Jesus Is son of God, I realised it and asked for forgiveness by tauba and rade shahada,

Tags: sin, shirk, evil-thoughts

And one day I somehow told that I don't beleive in sins,I realised what I told and asked for forgiveness by tauba and rade shahada and astagfirullah 100 times. I am scared that I won't be forgiven, am I forgiven and if I am not how can I be forgiven? Can you also give me advice to control evil thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Salam!

Bismillah. All praises and glory is to Allah.

My dear muslim friend dont worry!

Allah swt says in the Quran:
"Do not despair of the mercy of Allah"

Allah says in Surah al-mulk: ˹He is the One˺ Who created death and life in order to test which of you is best in deeds. And He is the Almighty, All-Forgiving.

Allah is the all forgiving, the most merciful. None of us are perfect. We are not created to be perfect. We sin and we get evil whispers. We have free will to choose what we want to do. The only creation of Allah that is created as perfect are the angels, and Allah knows best.

But we belive that our prophet Muhammad pbuh is a perfect example of how we should be. He is the best person and was sent as a mercy.
Even he pbuh used to ask for Allah's forgivness

So all of us sin, but we have to belive in the mercy of Allah. As long as you keep regretting your sin(s) and repent to Allah he will keep forgiving you even if your sins are as large as the sea!
He loves you and is all forgiving, merciful.

You are a person with great iman (faith) and you regret what you did so much! Dont worry! inshAllah you are already forgiven.
You should stop thinking about this and move on with your life.

As you know, we are not perfect so we should strive to do good deeds and become better people.

Also remember:
Whoever says SubhanAllah wa bihamdihi (glory be to Allah and praise him) a hundred times during the day, his sins are wiped away, even if they are like the foam of the sea. Hadith Sahih al-Bukhari; #7:168, Sahih Muslim; #4:2071.

Our beloved prophet Muhammad pbuh also told us that saying "SubhanAllah" one 100 times will make 1000 good deeds recorded for us, and 1000 bad deeds will be erased!

I belive in Allah and i belive that he is the most merciful and all forgiving like he has described himself and like our prophet pbuh has taught us. I advice you to also belive the same and belive that you have been forgiven 100%

People like you are special because you worry about your sins. That means that your iman is huge and great! This means that you 100% belive in Allah and in the hereafter. It also means that you are afraid and it is important to fear Allah but also to love Allah.

So again: Dont worry! inshAllah your sins have been forgiven long time ago :)

I also want to advice you to look at videoes on youtube related to islam. You will learn so much and it will not require any effort other than sitting infront of your computer/phone. You could start by typing "islamic reminder" or search "Mufti Menk" on youtube.

Advice to control evil deeds:
You should have rememberance of Allah. You should pray, think about Allah, read Quran, you can watch and learn from videoes i mentioned above etc. Do alot of dua. Just talk to Allah constantly, remember him, ask for help and seek refuge from Satan and all evil. There is no might or power except in Allah and if you ask Allah for help, then he will make everything easy for you!

You are really a true believer and you have nothing to worry about.

I hope that was good answers :)